# Setting up and controlling loads of LEDs

Tags: arduino, led, pcb-design

I need some input as I am a bit electronically challenged :) I know a few things but I am actually a programmer.
I am trying to find out how to do something like this:
http://bit.ly/1gx8Cc8

I was searching this forums and it led me to Peggy 2  from evil mad scientist.

So, I think the idea is the same, except I will not be able to use a flat circuit board- It will be inside of a big globe, as in the video.

I was thinking to use the following RGB LED lights, (as they say it uses less power, is more bright) .. http://bit.ly/19mBhds
It is the same ones used in the LED strips.

As in the video, i want to be able to have some animations going and setup my own. I was thinking Arduino.

I will probably end up with more than a 625 (25*25) LEDs.

Should I use Peggy 2 as a baseline and principles?
Should i use a flexible circuit board or any other suggestions - because it is inside a globe, it wont be on a big flat surface?

Any input will be really appreciated :) Just collecting some knowledge.

Comment: As a beginner project, it might be better to start smaller, as dealing with over a hundred Watts of power for the 625 LEDs, and tens of Amperes on the supply line, isn't trivial. Also, depending on the LED current regulation method used, that 625 LED set-up is going to dissipate a very significant amount of heat.

Comment: I agree with @Anindo. You should start way smaller. Depending on your experience, you should probably go for 60 to 100 LEDs first.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention that you're a beginner in electronics, you may find it easier to use a bunch of WS2812Bs instead of bare RGB 5050s; they can be controlled with fewer pins via software, rather than requiring a large mesh of connections to constant current sources and Darlington sinks.

With a steady hand you may be able to use point-to-point soldering instead of mounting them on a board, or you can possibly have one circuit board per LED and then solder those together (which will help with cooling). The supply lines will be required to handle more power than the data lines, so you may want to wire up the LEDs into multiple supply chains regardless of how you wire the data lines.

Keep in mind that however you do this, it will require a decent amount of power; each LED can consume a few hundred mW, and you need to supply the MCU as well.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the power requirement: 625 LEDs drawing (let's say) 20 mA each, and rated for, for instance, 3 Volts each, would require nearly **40 Watts** of power. If the supply is 5 Volts, the supply lines would tend towards around **8 Amperes** of load with all LEDs on.

Comment: Most of these displays are scanned, not solid on. Power usage would decrease accordingly.

Comment: must use multiplexing to reduce the power required or even could use PWM am i correct? @Passerby

Comment: @yogece depending on your needs, both. For example, http://www.instructables.com/id/Building-a-Daft-Punk-helmet-with-programmable-LED-/?ALLSTEPS has a 320 led matrix (5x 8x8 matrixes) and apparently only draws 800mA at full draw. Scale it up to 625 and 3 colors, you might be seeing under 5 amps for full white. This http://uiproductions.blogspot.com/2011/07/deadmau5-led-head-replica-at-comic-con.html has a 2 hour runtime with 2 4A batteries.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, having a solid learning curve here. So, in that video, they are building that mau5head, which is basically worn on your head and powered by batteries, so how long would batteries last if you have animations like that going? I don't think all of them go full white at one time ..  I will go smaller initially, maybe on flat board, to see what im doing, but when i built it in a dome like that, i want it to look good :)  I am pretty much wanting to build exactly what they have in that video.   Some more reading up :)

Comment: @Passerby That second link to uiproductions, is pretty much what I am Trying to build :) ... just do not know what components (besides the LEDs) I would need and how to set it up, I am all for building it, it is just I need to kinda know what to build before i can do it

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the WS2812 RGB LEDs with integrated controller.  They are connected in series and use a single pin for control.

An arduino can drive them but the maximum number you can drive depends on how fast you need them to refresh.

[Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com) sells a bunch of products using the WS2812 and they also have [a tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/advanced-coding) about how to use them.

Their estimate for power is between 1-3 Amps per 50 LEDs. So for 625 LEDs you will need about 40 Amps total.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the WS2812 Leds. So, running on batteries, how long should i be able to power that amount of LEDs if using animation and not all on the whole time?

Comment: @Cranzy: Depends on the batteries. But count on needing several amp-hours of high-C batteries.

Comment: Ok, this looks good, i see the OctoWS2811 library can drive up to 8 strips of the WS2812 leds ... But i think using a strip built the LEDs are to far apart. so i will probably need to buy them loosely and connect them closer together.